# Delete entry in Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a calculator using tkinter.
But after the user enters the first number I can't delete it. I'm using the method:

```
variable_name.delete(0,END)
```

But I get the error: name 'END' is not defined

This is one of the functions of the calculator, this one is for addition.

```
def sumar():
   primer_numero=entrada.get()
   global p_numero
   global operacion
   operacion="suma"
   p_numero=int(primer_numero)
   entrada.delete(0,END)
```

'entrada' is a variable that was defined in the code like this:

```
entrada = tk.Entry(width=25)
```

(I can post the entire code for more reference but is a little long)

Comment: I recommend using the literal string "end". END  is just a constant for the literal string "end", and whether it exists or not depends on how you imported tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You likely did `import tkinter as tk` based on your other code snippet which means you need to replace `END` with `tk.END`

**Alternative**

The other option would be doing
`from tkinter import *` and then use `END` without specifying the namespace but this would also require using `Entry` and other tkinter objects without the `tk.` prefixed